# How to get the value of a ComboBox within a DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, combobox

While this may be a simple problem, I'm having a heck of a time coming up with a solution.

I have a DataGrid with a ComboBox as an ItemRenderer for one of my columns. When the user selects a row, I want to get the ComboBox's selected value for the selected row.

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that the dataField2_Array property in myData is actually an Array is the dataProvider for the ComboBox. Each object in myData could have completely different values in that Array so the ComboBox in each row of the DataGrid could have completely different options to pick from.

Any suggestions?

Some sample code:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid"
  dataProvider="{myData}">
    <mx:columns>
      <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="dataField1" />
      <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="dataField2_Array">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
          <mx:Component>
            <mx:HBox paddingLeft="5">
              <mx:ComboBox id="myComboBox" dataProvider="{data.dataField2_Array}" />
            </mx:HBox>
          </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
      </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<mx:DataGrid ="MyDataGrid">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Resource" width="200" itemRenderer="com.myClasses.myGridDropdownRenderer"/>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Here is your itemRenderer for your datagrid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:ComboBox prompt="Please select a Rating" change="stuffChanged()" dataProvider="{data.dataField2_Array}"
     xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.Event;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.core.Application;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;



            override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
                super.data = value;

            }



           public function stuffChanged():void{
               var myListData:DataGridListData = DataGridListData(listData);
               var r:int=myListData.rowIndex;
               var c:int=myListData.columnIndex;
              //Application.application.whateverStuff[r+1][c]=this.value;
               Application.application.whateverStuff[r+1][c]=
              this.selectedItem.data;
              }



        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:ComboBox>
```

This will be in your main Application which will be holding this value.

```
[Bindable] public var whateverStuff:ArrayCollection;
```

Now when your data is changed, it holds the data. You click on the button store this value in a rows object.

```
[Bindable] public var rows:Object = new Object();
rows=Application.application.whateverStuff;
```

When your sending the value back to database, send all along with this rows object.

**Update:**

After i read your comment on the previous riposte, i came to know that each of your combo box has a different options. You should have mentioned it earlier.

When you click on the selected rows, you should able to collect the ID of the row, and this would ensure that only the ID of that row is getting updated in the database regardless even if you update your combo box of other rows.

Once your select a row, click and verify on which row ID you have selected using Alert or trace, then send that rows value alone through an event dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vino, but I'm not quite following you here. This looks like it will display the combobox in my datagrid, but how do I get the combobox's selected value when a datagrid row is selected?

For example, If someone double clicks a row to select it, I want to get the selected value of the combobox in that row.

Comment: I have updated the code, let me know if you need any more clarification or help

Comment: So if I've got this right, each time the user picks a value from the ComboBox, it updates the whateverStuff variable at the Application level. When a row is selected, it goes and grabs the data stored in the whateverStuff variable and passes to whatever method I'm using to update the database. What happens if the user selects a value from a ComboBox in one row and then clicks to select a completely different row? Would it send the data for the ComboBox that was changed to the database or the data for the ComboBox in the selected row?

Comment: This is a pretty heavy solution, but I believe it will work. I can't believe Flex doesn't have an easier way of doing this since this is a fairly common thing in .NET. Thanks again for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a function called myGrid_click to the click event of your DataGrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" dataProvider="{myData}" click="myGrid_click(event)" >
```

In this function, store the grid's selectedIndex and use that to get the object out of its dataProvider (let's say it's an array of MyObjects, and we're interested in the dataField2 property of these MyObjects):

```
public function myGrid_click(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var index:int = myGrid.selectedIndex;
    var obj:MyObject = myData[index];
    var value:String = obj.dataField2;
}
```

If, as is often the case, the object isn't storing the real value, and is just storing an index to a lookup table (dataField2_Array?), write a for loop to iterate over dataField2_Array looking for that value (actualValue) and assign it to a previously declared variable of greater scope (selectedRowComboBoxValue):

```
public function myGrid_click(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var index:int = myGrid.selectedIndex;
    var obj:MyObject = myData[index];
    var value:int = obj.dataField2;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < dataField2_Array.length; i++) {
        if (value == dataField2_Array[index].id) {
            selectedRowComboBoxValue = dataField2_Array.actualValue;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I probably worded my initial question poorly because my situation is a *little* different than average. What you're suggesting looks like it would work if the objects stored in myData contained just the value that was selected for the ComboBox. In my situation, the DataField2_Array property in each object in my ArrayCollection actually contains an Array that I'm using as the dataProvider for the comboBox. The ComboBox in each row in the DataGrid could have a completely different set of options to pick from.